# How can I see where a module or class was `require`-d in?

Tags: ruby

I’m having trouble hunting down where in a project a particular library is being `require`-ed in.

Is there a method or technique that can tell me the filename and line?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention a system you are using but you can use `grep` or `ack-grep` for this task:

```
ack-grep "require 'simple_form'"
```

Comment: The trick here is that the require statement may be coming in from gem somewhere. I suppose I could search my entire local gems directory, but I was hoping for a more elegant approach along the lines of [source_location](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html#method-i-source_location)

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, you could monkey patch require and print out `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`